# Inject the values with singleton scope using class name

Tags: java, spring, caching, dependency-injection

I am new to spring. My class diagram is like this

```
public abstract class Cache{
    refreshCache() {
      clearCache();
      createCache();
    }
    clearCache();
    createCache();
    getName();
}

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
@Qualifier("category")
class Category extends Cache implements ICategory{}

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
@Qualifier("attr")
class Attr extends Cache implements IAttr{}

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
@Qualifier("country")
class Country extends Cache implements ICountry{}
```

By default the scope of spring beans are singleton. So I want to create the cache management service. With reflection I will get all the classes which extends Cache class but the all the cache are with singleton scope if I will instantiate them with "`new`" I am getting new object but other will get different object and other class are inject it like following.

```
Class A {
  @inject
  Country c
}

Class B {
  @inject
  Attr attr
}
```

Every injection is using the same cache so if I create it with "`new`" refresh will not reflect to them.

P.S. - The main goal is to create a class which will know all the classes extending the Cache class and given a name (`getName()` Function from Cache class) it will refresh the respective cache. If spring have this functionality that will be good enough.

Comment: Just add a collection `List<Cache>` put `@Autowired` on it and you will get al bean instances of that type. No need to hack around yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The main goal is to create a class which will know all the classes extending the Cache class and given a name (getName() Function from Cache class)"

Just create a collection with @Autowired or @Inject

```
@Autowired
List<Cache>
```